# Custom environment to accept \item

Tags: tables, lists, environments

How can I create an environment that takes items in a way similar to lists?

Example:

```
\begin{myEnv}
\item{AAA}{BBB}
\item{CCC}{DDD}
\end{myEnv}
```

I'd like the above do something like

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
header1 & header2 & header3 & header4 \\ \hline
AAA & BBB & & \\ \hline
CCC & CCC & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I'm not entirely clear on your usage, the following is most likely what you're after. The given minimal working example shows your original `tabular` construction, followed by a `myEnv` construction. Each `\item` in within `myEnv` takes four arguments for the four columns. However, this can also be modified to only take two as in your example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan/org/pkg/booktabs
\newenvironment{myEnv}
  {\renewcommand{\item}[4]{##1&##2&##3&##4\\}% \item{<one>}{<two>}{<three>}{<four>}
   \tabular{*{4}{l}}
     \toprule
     header1 & header2 & header3 & header 4 \\
     \midrule
  }
  {\bottomrule\endtabular}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
header1 & header2 & header3 & header4 \\ \hline
AAA & BBB & & \\ \hline
CCC & CCC & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{myEnv}
  \item{AAA}{BBB}{CCC}{DDD}
  \item{EEE}{FFF}{GGG}{HHH}
\end{myEnv}

\end{document}
```

I took the liberty of using the [`booktabs` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to produce the second `myEnv` table, since it produces professional-looking tables (without the use of vertical rules).

The redefinition of `\item` is local to the environment `myEnv`, and can therefore still be used in other list environments. Alternatively, you could make your own `\item` environment (say, `\myItem`) which would work only inside `myEnv`.